# Integrating AirPlay to iOS app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-tv, airplay, control-center

I want to **cast a radio stream through AirPlay** (to an AppleTV). I've researched a lot related to this topic, but I found the documentation really poor.

This is the Apple documentation for AirPlay 2: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/airplay_2/getting_airplay_2_into_your_app

I found out that `AVRoutePickerView` is only available after iOS 11. Below iOS 11, `MPVolumeView` needs to be used.

I've checked the iOS version, integrated these classes, the cast is working, buy not how I want it

A **black screen** appears on the TV while playing and I **can't control the volume** of the cast.

Can anyone show me how to integrate AirPlay into an iOS app simple and clearly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *problem was* I set on my `AVPlayer` object the **`allowsExternalPlayback`** to `true`. This property's "ancestor" in earlier versions of iOS (until 6.0), was more meaningful with the name of: `allowsAirPlayVideo`.

**SO** if you **call this** `allowsExternalPlayback = false` on your player, the **black screen disappears** and you **can** also **control the volume** of the radio cast.

Comment: No, but as far as I remember you have to set this property to `false` on your player instance:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387441-allowsexternalplayback